# Compare consecutive columns of a file and obtain the number of matched elements

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want to compare consecutive columns of a file and return the number of matched elements. I would prefer to use shell scripting or `awk`. Here is a sample `bash`/`AWK` script that I am trying to use.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 

do

  for j in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

     do
  `awk "$i == $j" phased.txt | wc -l`

     done
done
```

I have a file of size 147189*828 and I want to compare each columns and return the number of matched elements in a 828*828 matrix(A similarity matrix).
This would be fairly easy in MATLAB, but, it takes a long time to load huge files. I can compare two columns and return the number of matched elements with the following awk command:

```
awk '$3==$4' phased.txt | wc -l
```

but would need some help to do it for the entire file.

A snippet of the data that I'm working on is:

```
# sampleID  HGDP00511  HGDP00511   HGDP00512   HGDP00512   HGDP00513  HGDP00513   

M rs4124251       0       0            A            G          0          A

M rs6650104       0       A            C            T          0          0

M rs12184279      0       0            G            A          T          0

................................................................................
```

After comparing I will compute a 6*6 matrix in this case: containing the matching percentage of these columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, variables need a `$` to be interpreted, so your `awk "$i == $j" phased.txt | wc -l` will be evaluated as   `awk "3 == 4" phased.txt | wc -l`; then, because of your backticks (`` ` ``), the shell will try to execute that as a command. To get awk to see `$3 == $4`, you need to add `\$`:   `awk "\$$i == \$$j" phased.txt | wc -l`.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     
do
  for j in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  do
    awk "\$$i == \$$j" phased.txt | wc -l
  done
done
```

Though you'll probably want to show which combination you're evaluating:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     
do
  for j in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  do
    echo "$i $j: $(awk "\$$i == \$$j" phased.txt | wc -l)"
  done
done
```

You could actually just do the count in awk directly

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9     
do
  for j in 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
  do
    echo "$i $j: $(awk "\$$i == \$$j {count++}; END{print count}" phased.txt)"
  done
done
```

Finally, you could just do the whole thing in awk; it'll almost certainly be faster but to be honest it's not that much cleaner: [UNTESTED]

```
#!/usr/bin/env awk -f

{
    for (i = 3; i <= 9; i++) {
        for (j = 3; j <= 9; j++) {
            if ($i == $j) {
                counts[i, j]++
            }
        }
    }
}

END {
    for (i = 3; i <= 9; i++) {
        for (j = 3; j <= 9; j++) {
            printf "%d = %d: %d\n", i, j, counts[i, j]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kevin! That ran smoothly :) 
I was trying the $$ but your '\$' did the trick !! Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help. In case you didn't figure it out, `$$` is the shell's PID.